# dynamic Search? how?

Tags: django, django-models

That way or you can do this:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    instance = model_class.objects(key = value)
```

or can only be done this way?:

```
instance = model_class.objects(pk = value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deliver keyword arguments by [unpacking the dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments):

```
instance = model_class.objects.filter(**data)
```

where keys in `data` dictionary are `model_class` field names.